# can not specify disabled and will not enter the name for the class of how it should look

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button where to have one class with the color that I have made in my js file. at the same time it must make a disabled of whether you can click on it or not. So the return true or false in the two areas.

I've looked at it here:

[ngclass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Right now so does my disabled not while it will not specify the color that I have made behind the js file.

Html:

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="Disabled" ng-class="{Color: Color}" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-success">
   {{ReadyNow()}}
</button>
```

js file:

```
var app = angular.module('ModifyUser', [])
app.controller('RetUserInfo', function ($scope) {
    $scope.ReadyNow = function () {
        //Checking up on everything is empty first.
        if ($scope.firstnameValue != null && $scope.lastnameValue != null && $scope.email != null && $scope.adgangskode != null) {
            //says now that you can create content.
            return "Ready to update now!";
            $scope.Disabled = true;
            $scope.Color = "btn btn-success";
        }
        else {
            //Says that more is needed to update content.
            return "Cant not update"
            $scope.Disabled = false;
            $scope.Color = "btn btn-warning";
        }
    };
    //DONE
});
```

Comment: You are returning from both cases before assigning `$scope.Disabled` and `$scope.Color`. Maybe you want to use `console.log` instead of returning?

Comment: @JackA. Thanks for the comment. It was so the only option I had not just tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button has the `btn` class added already, and you basically want to add `btn-warning` or `btn-success` depending on a condition.

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="Disabled" ng-class="{'btn-warning: !Success, 'btn-success': Success}" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-success">
   {{ReadyNow()}}
</button>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('ModifyUser', [])
app.controller('RetUserInfo', function ($scope) {
    $scope.ReadyNow = function () {
        //Checking up on everything is empty first.
        if ($scope.firstnameValue != null && $scope.lastnameValue != null && $scope.email != null && $scope.adgangskode != null) {
            //says now that you can create content.
            $scope.Disabled = true;
            $scope.Success = true;
            return "Ready to update now!";
        }
        else {
            //Says that more is needed to update content.
            $scope.Disabled = false;
            $scope.Success = false;
            return "Cant not update"
        }
    };
    //DONE
});
```

Also note that you return *after* you've set the scope variables as **Jack** mentioned in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I see what you mean now when you tell me what I did wrong. I need not to repeat myself too much !. "DRY" = Do not repeat yourself. It's super nice to you shown me how I could get it to work. Hope you will give me a +1 for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like the following instead of doing the whole validation javascript.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-success" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"> 
    Submit
</button>
```